# C# code refactoring?

Tags: c#, marshalling

How to convert this code:

```
MYCLASS ebt = new MYCLASS();
ebt.cbStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(ebt);
```

into this:

```
MYCLASS ebt = new MYCLASS(cbStruct = Marshal.SizeOf('What comes here?'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the size of the type instead:

```
MYCLASS ebt = new MYCLASS { cbStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MYCLASS)) };
```

Also note braces rather than parentheses to use initialiser syntax.

Comment: Oops! I did the same earlier before asking the question, without any typos that for sure and it was not working, now it is.

Comment: Also you guess it very right, MYCLASS is a struct so all Constructor answers are wrong. +10 more for this.

Answer (score 3):

modify the MYCLASS ctor,

```
public MYCLASS()
{
   cbStruct = Marshall.SizeOf(this);
}
```

Comment: Nice variation of itowlson's example.

Comment: Just to add, this is permitted only if MYCLASS is a class.  Many interop types are structs, and the default constructor for a struct can't be specified in C# -- it always initialises all fields to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MYCLASS` constructor that takes a `cbStruct` parameter.